# Integrate under assumptions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I am trying to solve the following integral:
$$\int_0^\infty u^{\sigma-1} \exp\left[-c u^\sigma\right] \mathrm{d}u$$
under the assumptions $\sigma \in (0,1)$ and $c>0$.
I know the result is
$$\dfrac{1}{c \sigma}.$$
However, using the following code in *Mathematica*

```
 Integrate[ Power[u, sigma - 1] * Exp[-c*Power[u, sigma]] , {u, 0, Infinity},  Assumptions -> {c > 0 && 0 < sigma && sigma <1 && Element[c, Reals] && Element[sigma, Reals]}]
```

I obtain

> Integrate Integral of e^(-c u^sigma) u^(-1+sigma) does not converge on {0,[Infinity]}.

Surprisingly, deleting just the assumption $\sigma <1$, it works as expected, that is running

```
Integrate[Power[u, sigma - 1] * Exp[-c*Power[u, sigma]] , {u, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {c > 0 && 0 < sigma && Element[c, Reals] &&Element[sigma, Reals]}]
```

I obtain

> 1/(c sigma).

I do not understand why adding a restriction changes the general result, but I do not find my mistake.

**Edit:** In the version 12.2 of *Mathematica* both the expressions work correctly. I assume they fixed the bug.

Comment: It is a weird behavior indeed. This: `Integrate[u^(s - 1)*Exp[-c*u^s], {u, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {c > 0, s > 0}]`returns the expected result. But this: `Integrate[u^(s - 1)*Exp[-c*u^s], {u, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {c > 0, s > 0, s < 1}]` brings the error message you mentioned. I would report it to Wolfram.

Comment: As best I can tell there is a faulty convergence test in play. Treating it as a bug (belatedly).

Comment: It would be better if you put your finding as an answer.  I can delete mine, if you want to post it instead.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2. I added the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In V12.2, we get the expected answer:

```
Integrate[
 Power[u, sigma - 1]*Exp[-c*Power[u, sigma]], {u, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {c > 0 && 0 < sigma && Element[c, Reals] && 
    Element[sigma, Reals]}]

(*  1/(c sigma)  *)
```

I assume they fixed the bug.